# Deploying Web Applications to Running Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have an instance of Tomcat 8. I also have a script, that generates `war` file. I need to deploy that `war` to my Tomcat and start it from my Java application. As I understand, if I just copy the `war` file into `webapps/` dir, I would be deployed but not started.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Test what? That copying would not start the application? Already did it

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/

Comment: Yeah, thanks! You think I didn't try to find my answer there? I need some kind of command-line solution, because I need to invoke it from INSIDE my application, so all that GUI stuff is not for me

Answer (score 0):

Once you start the tomcat server, go to tomcat homepage http://localhost:8080/

Click on Manager App. If login required, check the tomcat-users.xml in Tomcat/conf folder.

```
<user password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,manager-gui,admin,admin-gui,admin-script" username="tomcat"/>
```

Login using tomcat/tomcat (username and password)

Once on manager page (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) Under deploy heading, choose war file to deploy.

Once deployed, start the war.

Comment: That's exactly the point of my question -- I can do all that, but I need to do it from INSIDE my Java application, I'm looking for some kind of command-line solution

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. The application is a JSF page, which generates a config file for external script. Then it runs this script, and the output is the `war` file I need started in Tomcat